# It is possible to make the values selected on the first input be displayed on the second input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
<StyledFieldsRow>

//First input
 
   <WhiteSelect
        tabIndex={7}
            requiredField
            placeholder="Select one"
            name="aso"
            defaultValue={{
              label: 'Normal',
              value: false,
            }}
            label="Type of service"
            options={[
              { label: 'ASO', value: true },
              { label: 'Normal', value: false },
            ]}
            menuPlacement="top"
      />
         

//Second input

       <WhiteInput
            style={{
              width: isMobile ? '100%' : '',
            }}
            name="note"
            label="Comments"
            tabIndex={9}
            placeholder="Enter notes"
         />
</StyledFieldsRow>
```

I've tried rewrite this in multiple ways, but none had worked and now I'm out of ideas. If anyone knows how to do this please answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react's `useState` hook.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

function ... {
  const [secondInputValue, setSecondInputValue] = useState(null)

  function handleSetSecondInputValue(event) {
    setSecondInputValue(event.target.value)
  }

  ...

  <StyledFieldsRow>
    <WhiteSelect
      ref={whiteSelectRef}
      tabIndex={7}
      requiredField
      placeholder='Select one'
      name='aso'
      defaultValue={{
        label: 'Normal',
        value: false
      }}
      label='Type of service'
      options={[
        {
          label: 'ASO',
          value: true
        },
        {
          label: 'Normal',
          value: false
        }
      ]}
      MenuPlacement='top'
      onChange={handleSetSecondInputValue}
    />

    <WhiteInput
      style={{
        width: isMobile ? '100%' : '',
      }}
      name='note'
      label='Comments'
      tabIndex={9}
      placeholder='Enter notes'
      value={secondInputValue}
    />
  </StyledFieldsRow>

  ...

}
```